# Switch between menu items WPF?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application. I have different users of this application and each user has a different level associated with them. People with higher level dont have access to some menu items.

Is there a way to switch between the menu items? Is toggling the individual menu item's visibility an efficient way to accomplish this? Is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this using bindings and converters. Basically if you have a property on the `DataContext` of the menu (which will be inherited by the menu items) that specifies the level of permissions; then you could bind that to the visibility of the menu items.

Obviously, because the permissions would not be implicitly convertible to the `Visibility` enum, you would have to create an implementation of the [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) interface, which would be specific to converting permissions to visibilities, and vice versa, based on the current permissions level. This would also require the converter having some concept of the current permissions level, so either you would want to give it access to some static property (which I would not advise), or you would need to gain hold of the converter instance (making sure you only use one instance) and pass the current permissions level to it.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different ways to do this.  Toggling visibility is one way, but if you want your code to readable for other people, I would suggest implementing some kind of design pattern.

I would suggest either following MVVM or MVC patterns.  That would mean you would need to create different views for different users.

As for something simple like menu items, you could seperate that part of your UI into a User Control, and in that User Control, have different XAMLs for different users.  Then in the code, have the correct XAML (view) be displayed based on which user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `Visibility` property works for `MenuItem`s. If you paste the below code into [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/), you'll see that the Edit menu is hidden, and so is Tools > Item 2.

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem Header="_File"/>
  <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
  <MenuItem Header="_Tools">
    <MenuItem Header="Item 1"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Item 3"/>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

You can also change the `Visibility` programmatically, or databind it to a property on your viewmodel.